# Can't use 'three.js' library remotely

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to use `three.js` library that's located online, and I've included a path to `three.js` file into my `<script>` tag inside `index.html`. But my script doesn't work because there's no access to `three.js` library.

```
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to use `three.js` library remotely?

Comment: Where did you get that URL? [The documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation) tells to use unpkg.com.

Comment: I recommend you don't use that file for production code. The library is updated once a month and eventually something in your code will break without warning. You should copy the file to your server to prevent surprise incompatibilities in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Marquizzo, I consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It is working in my project.

If it still wont working, try to find here, how to install this: [Instalation Three.js](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation)

Comment: @AndyFedoroff that’s a separate question. Research import/export JS (also called es modules)